NSwag generates a type where it should be nullable string
I have a OpenAPI specification, which has one of the properties specified like so:

"s10_unit": {
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "type": "null"
    }
  ],
  "title": "S10 Unit"
},

the generated class looks like this:
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "14.2.0.0 (NJsonSchema v11.1.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
public partial class S10_unit
{

  private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>? _additionalProperties;

  [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonExtensionData]
  public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
  {
    get { return _additionalProperties ?? (_additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>()); }
    set { _additionalProperties = value; }
  }

}

My CSPROJ OpenApiReference looks like so:
  <ItemGroup>
    <OpenApiReference Include="OpenAPIs\openapi.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" ClassName="CryptocurrencySustainabilityApiClient" Options="SingleClientFromPathSegments">
        <SourceUri>https://v2.api.carbon-ratings.com/mica/openapi.json</SourceUri>
        <Options>/GenerateSyncMethods:true /OperationGenerationMode:SingleClientFromOperationId /ClientClassAccessModifier:internal /JsonLibrary:SystemTextJson /GenerateOptionalParameters:true /GenerateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable:true /GenerateNullableReferenceTypes:true /ExposeJsonSerializerSettings:true</Options>
    </OpenApiReference>
  </ItemGroup>

The problem is that during deserialization I get an exception:

The JSON value could not be converted to MySolution.S10_unit. Path: $.units.s10_unit | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1876.

The value that I get from the API is a normal string:
"units": {
    "s10_unit": "percentage share",
...

Is there a way to fix this?
I tried to build the client with NSwag Studio, but the result is the same.
Is it a problem with the OpenAPI specification or NSwag?

I'm not aware that there is a Null Type in OpenAPI. OpenAPI knows about nullable types but not a Null Type. When i import your OpenAPI json here into the editor is will bark about exactly that.
